# Scale_Pos_Weight Before or After Train Test Split?

Tags: machine-learning, python, boosting

I know XGBoost has a scale_pos_weight we can add in where we take (positives/negatives) and we get our coefficient. However, what is the sample we are drawing from? Is it the whole X, Y set? Or is it after the train, test, split?